# React to event "Creating a Node" in Drupal with MuleStudio

Tags: events, drupal, drupal-7, mule, mule-studio

I want to build a Flow that when a Node (an article) is created in Drupal, the Title of the Node is published to Facebook as Message. The publishing of Messages to Facebook is no problem, but i have no idea how to get the Event of Creating new Content in a Drupal Installation. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a pure Mule point of view with no changes to Drupal you could poll the index-nodes operation of the Drupal connector http://mulesoft.github.io/drupal-connector/mule/drupal-config.html#index-nodes

```
<poll frequency="60000">
    <drupal:index-nodes startPage="1" pagesize="10">
        <drupal:fields>
            <drupal:field>nid</drupal:field>
            <drupal:field>type</drupal:field>
            <drupal:field>title</drupal:field>
        </drupal:fields>
    </drupal:index-nodes>
</poll>
```

You would then have to somehow persist a marker such as the last modified date or the last page number in a persistent object-store so it can be read on the next poll so you know which nodes have been processed or which page to start from. If you're using Mule 3.5... then there's a new "watermark" feature for that specific type of functionality. A bit of info on watermarks here: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6861

However a better solution to polling would be to use a message queue such as ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ that Drupal could publish a message to via Stomp for example and Mule can pick up it up via a JMS inbound endpoint or an AMQP inbound endpoint - dependant on what messaging you go with. This way messages are pushed rather than pulled, but does require Drupal customisation.

Comment: Thats a good Point, too. I have done this with a Flow which indexes all Nodes, saves the ID´s in a Varaible and calls itself again. Then the Flow compars the actual Payload with the Variable and looks for new ID´s. If there are new nodes the flow calls another flow to proccess the data.

Answer (score 1):

From the Drupal side of things you could write a simple [custom module](https://drupal.org/developing/modules) and implement [`hook_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    push_article($node->title);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a written a module with your suggested hook_node_insert, inside the hook i perform a php cURL execute and call localhost:port with the parameters ?title=$title&nid=$nid. So Mule gets this information as inbound properties. Thats a very good idea but i have accept the other answer because i want to do solve this problem only with the capabilities of Mule.